# Parse an array within an object

Tags: php, jquery, json

My data is coming from PHP like this:

```
auth0: Object
"client_id: "1234"
tables: Array[2]
  0: Object
     clients_avail: "demo"
  1: Object
     clients_avail: "4532t78"
```

EDIT: Here's the actual JSON:

```
{"auth":{"id":"bob"},"tables":[{"clients_avail":"demo"},{"clients_avail":"4532t78"}]}
```

The above is retrieved like so:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'getit.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            id_token: my_token
        },
        success: function(data) {
$.each(full_data, function (data) {
$('#clients_avail').append("<option>" + data.tables.clients_avail + "</option>");
 $('#my_id').text(data.auth.id);
}
});
```

This is coming back uncaught error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clients_avail' of undefined
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: can you do a `console.log(data)` as the first line of the success handler and see what is logged in the browser console

Comment: also see the network tab(developer tools) to see what is the response text and past it here

Comment: @ArunPJohny The object that I have in my code is what I get from `console.log(data)`.

Comment: then try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`

Comment: I get this with `stringify`: `{"auth":["{\"id\":"bob"],"tables":[[{"clients_avail":"demo"},{"clients_avail":"4532t78"}]]}`

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.tables))` now

Comment: `tables` is an array of arrays, try `data.tables[0][0].clients_avail` to access first one. You should probably organize your PHP output better.

Comment: there is a double array in `tables` value.... why is it

Comment: I updated my PHP to make what came back a little simpler. Can you check out my edited answer and see if that helps? If I do this: `console.log(data.tables[0].clients_avail);` I get back one of the objects, but I need to do an `each` to get all the possible tables.

Comment: You need to loop over `full_data.tables`, not over `full_data`... This would be a lot easier if you posted the actual JSON string you are getting back instead of dump of some sort.

Comment: Just added the JSON to my edited answer. Does that help? I'm able to get out the `auth` part now with `console.log(data.auth.id)`, but still can't get anything out of `tables`

Comment: @prodigitalson Your last response did the trick. I was looping over the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an array, you need to iterate

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getit.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        id_token: my_token
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.tables, function (data) {
            $('#clients_avail').append("<option>" + data.clients_avail + "</option>");
        })
        $('#my_id').text(data.auth[0].id);
    }
});
```

Also in your case the `auth` is an array of objects, which I think is unnecessary, so try to make your response like `{"auth":{"id":"bob"},"tables":[{"clients_avail":"demo"},{"clients_avail":"‌​4532t78"}]}`, then `$('#my_id').text(data.auth.id);`

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the argument inside your $.each(); try doing it like this.

```
success: function(data) {
   $.each(data.tables[0], function (k, val) {
      $('#clients_avail').append("<option>" + val.clients_avail + "</option>");
      $('#my_id').text(data.auth.id);
   }
```

I as what **skobaljic** told you you should organize your json or use json_encode() to output your data.